# Data Migration from MS Access to Oracle-sql Developer using ODBC link

Tags: ms-access, odbc, oracle-sqldeveloper, database-migration, type-mismatch

I'm migrating data from Microsoft Access 2013 to Oracle-SQL Developer(Oracle client 12.1). I'm using ODBC link, I can migrate my tables but the conversion of the data types isn't correct. In fact, all the data types re converted to  VARCHAR2(eg. NUMBER(Access)becomes VARCHAR2(Oracle)).

How can I fix it ? Is there any way to convert types explicitly ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to do it in two steps, first migrating to MS SQL server. You can use the free Express Edition and the free Access to MS SQL migration tool which allows you to manually map MS Access types to MS SQL Server types. It should be fairly easy to find out what MS SQL Server types migrate to in Oracle-SQL so you can make the necessary mappings on the fist step.

Answer (score 0):

There are several approaches.

One approach is to build the table structure in Oracle (use Oracle design tools). You then link to that oracle table in Access.

You can now run a append query in Access to send the table from Access to Oracle. The result will be data type mappings of your choice. And you can even build such a append query with the Access query bulder.

Another approach is to send the data from Access to Oracle. You don’t mention now how you are doing this. But, most data types will and do get translated correctly if you use the transfer database command with this format:

```
Sub SendToSQL()

  Dim strLocalTable    As String
  Dim strSQLTable      As String

  Dim strSQLDataBase  As String

  strSQLDataBase = "test3"

  strLocalTable = "tblFood"
  strSQLTable = "tblFood"

  Dim strODBC As String

  strODBC = "ODBC;DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER=ALBERTKALLAL-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Trusted_Connection=Yes;DATABASE="

  strODBC = strODBC & strSQLDataBase

  DoCmd.TransferDatabase acExport, "ODBC Database", _
      strODBC, acTable, strLocalTable, strSQLTable

End Sub
```

The above should send + create the table  in Oracle, and you should retain “most” of the correct data types  when you do the above.

Of course the above example uses a SQL server connection string, and you would of course replace the above connection string with a oracle one.